# Static thread safety and initialization order

Tags: c++, multithreading, constructor, initialization

I've come across a threading issue within some code I'm working on.
MyStruct gets constructed on multiple threads which causes the program to sometimes crash within staticFunc. Big surprise as the code is accessing an unsafe variable value (MSVC 2012 compiler).

```
struct MyStruct : baseClass
{
    MyStruct() : baseClass(myFunc())
    {
    }

    static int* myFunc()
    {
        static int value[const_size] = get_array();
        // Do some complex stuff to value.
        return &value[0];
    }
};
```

My question is, what is the best way to solve this?
My first thought would be to remove the static declarations all together.
This actually allowed the unit tests I wrote to pass.

```
struct MyStruct : baseClass
{
    MyStruct() : baseClass(myFunc())
    {
    }

    int* myFunc()
    {
        this->value = get_array();
        // Do some complex stuff to value.
        return &this->value[0];
    }

    int value[const_size];
};
```

But I'm concerned, isn't it undefined behavior if value is used before constructed/initialized?

Construction order:

1. baseClass constructor calls myFunc()
2. myFunc() uses value.
3. WAIT! value has not been initialized by MyStruct's constructor yet!

Is this what is happening or am i missing something and if so, what would be the correct way of solving this? static mutex?

Edit: I am using MSVC 2012(static is NOT thread safe) and moving to a different compiler is NOT an option.

Comment: in `c++11` static also implies thread safeness, so one solution would be to just use a `c++11` compiler

Comment: @bolov And also move the "Do some complex stuff to value" into a function used to initialise the static variable.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes, I missed that. to OP: The reason for that is that initialization of static variables is thread safe. If yo initialize and then assign, you lose that guarantee.

Comment: I edited my post.  I am using MSVC 2012 so static is not thread safe.  I do not have the option of switching compilers either.

Comment: how can baseClass ctor call a method of a derived class (MyStruct in this case)

Answer (score 0):

The first question is whether you want to share the value between different thread or whether it is ok for each thread to store its own value.

If you want to share the value across threads you will need to protect all access with a Critical Section.

If you are ok with different threads holding different values, you will need to look at thread local storage.  c++11 provides the thread_local for this purpose but I am not sure if MSVC supports this. Otherwise you can use TlsAlloc, TlsGetValue, TlsSetValue and TlsFree.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::call_once`, it was literally invented to solve this problem. From memory you don't need thread-safe statics for file-scope statics as they must be initialized prior to `main` being entered, so there's no chance of anybody having any threads in your code before it's initialized.

```
// Place the func_flag at file scope.
static std::once_flag my_func_flag;
class blah {
    static const int* myFunc()
    {
        static int value[const_size];
        std::call_once(my_func_flag, [] {
            // perform ALL mutations of value in here.
            value = get_array();
        });
        // Read-only from here on.
        return &value[0];
    }
};
```